# Highlight/multicolor substring of axis tick label in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, colors, label, substring, highlight

I am curious about how to highlight or multicolor the text in axis of x, here is the example of output, how can I label the red color of 'TGFB1' within the word 'TGFB1-EGFR', this is the pair of ligand and receptor in biology. If you have some idea or know other package which do achieve this, please tell me, thanks in advance.

[image]
Best,
Wei

Answer (score 1):

I find the `ggtext` github package very convenient in doing this. It allows html and markdown styling of text. Here is an example using the Iris dataset that you could apply on your own data.

Briefly, you wrap your labels in html colour coding and set the theme element to a markdown element.

```r
library(ggtext) # remotes::install_github("wilkelab/ggtext")
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = function(x) {
      paste0("<i style='color:#FF0000'>Iris </i>",
             "<i style='color:#0000FF'>", x ,"</i>")
    }
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>